# Los tipos de datos date y datetime en consultas SQL server desde JAVA

Tags: java, sql

Estoy haciendo una consulta a una BD datos SQL server pasando parámetros desde un programa en JAVA.
Me devuelve una excepción que dice : "los tipos de datos date y datetime son incompatibles con el operador greater than or equal to".

Este es el código.

```
private static final String SELECT_MIN_HORA = "SELECT MIN(HORA_SALIDA) AS HORA FROM ESK_PETICIONES WHERE(FECHA = ?)  AND HORA_SALIDA >= ? AND HORA_SALIDA <= ?



public static java.sql.Time select_MinHora_L00(LocalTime hora1, LocalTime hora2, Calendar fecha1)throws Exception{
   
   java.sql.Time hora=null; //Inicializar la hora
   
   ResultSet rs=null;
   PreparedStatement st=null;
   Datasource data=null;
   
   try{
          
        data=new Datasource();
        st=data.getStatement(SELECT_MIN_HORA,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        
        java.sql.Time time1 = Time.valueOf( hora1 );//Pasar de LocalTime a Java.sql.time
        st.setTime(1, time1);
        java.sql.Time time2 = Time.valueOf( hora2 );//Pasar de LocalTime a Java.sql.time
        st.setTime(2, time2);
        
        java.util.Date fecha=fecha1.getTime(); //Pasar de Calendar a java.sql.Date
        java.sql.Date fsql= new java.sql.Date(fecha.getTime());
       
        st.setDate(3, fsql);  
        
    
        
        rs=data.ejecutarSelect(st);
        
        
        while(rs.next()){    
            hora=rs.getTime("HORA");
            
        }
        //Cerrar el ResultSet
        rs.close();
        return hora;//DEvuelve la hora en formato Sql
        
    }catch(Exception ex){
        throw ex;
    }finally{
        if(st!=null){
            //Cerrar la consulta parametrizada
            st.close();
            //Cerrar la conexion.
            data.cerrarConexion();
        }
    }    
}
```

Se pasan dos parámetros de hora tipo LocalTime y supongo que el error está allí. He probado también de esta manera pero tampoco me funciona. El error de esta vez es de sintaxis.

```
private static final String SELECT_MIN_HORA = "SELECT MIN(HORA_SALIDA) AS HORA FROM ESK_PETICIONES WHERE(FECHA = ?) AND HORA_SALIDA >= (CAST(? AS TIME(0)) AND HORA_SALIDA <= (CAST(? AS TIME(0))";
```

Dice error de sintaxis incorrecta de la palabra clave AND

Comment: Hola Luis , esta consulta "SELECT MIN(HORA_SALIDA) AS HORA FROM ESK_PETICIONES WHERE(FECHA = ?) AND HORA_SALIDA >= (CAST(? AS TIME(0)) AND HORA_SALIDA <= (CAST(? AS TIME(0))"  te funciona si lo haces en tu bd??